# How do I go about coding an expanding image bounding box/frame when clicked on?

Tags: html, css, image, click, bounding-box

So basically i would like to make image bounding boxes expand when clicked on. I don't want the images to expand but rather the bounding box sort of like in adobe indesign(if you are familiar with it) when you double click an image and you can move the image within the frame. Is this even possible? I recently got into coding and would like to know how i would go about coding this. Can this all be done through css or would i need to use javascript? I illustrated the concept to help further explain what I'm talking about. Please excuse me if i am incorrectly using terminology.

[image]

Comment: You choice of colors is making my eyes bleed.

Comment: Have you attempted any code at all? You'll get a better response if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: FWIW, your question is clear, and could be answered (with multiple right answers); but most users here want to see some research and development effort from the asker.